# how to use context menu on listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I really not know, how to use context menu on listview in android. So please provide me some code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the registerForContextMenu(...) function in your Activity for your ListView.

Check the accepted answer in this thread:
[Custom ListView and context menu. How to get it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972945/custom-listview-and-context-menu-how-to-get-it)