# Context menu is not showing on Android list item long press

Tags: android, listview

Am stuck with the long press on the list view i have added

```
registerForContextMenu(this.objListView);
```

on the on create method. and my onCreateContextMenu is follows

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    System.out.println("ENTERED IN THE CONTEXT MENU BLOCK");
    if (v.getId() == R.id.booksLV) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        String objBook = userVector.get(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(objBook);
        String[] menuItems = {"Edit","Delete" };
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    }
}

 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/booksLV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"

            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:paddingRight="1dip"
             >
        </ListView>
```

Custom adapter components

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem_test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameLL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/pure_white_color"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headingLL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/off_white_color" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headingTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
              android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

oncreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        System.out.println(width + " ++++++++++++++++++++ " + height);
        Toast.makeText(this, width + " " + height, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (width == 240 && height == 400) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist_exp_h);
        } else if (width == 480 && height == 856) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist_exp_h);
        } else if (width == 480 && height == 854) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist_exp_h);
        } else if (width == 600 && height == 976) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist_exp_mdpi_h);
        } else if (width == 600 && height == 1024) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist_exp_mdpi_h);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_flat_accountlist);
        }

        float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        objListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.booksLV);

        registerForContextMenu(objListView);

        selectedIndex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedIndex);


        showProcessDialog();
        getAccounts();



    }
```

The context menu is not showing on the long press

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: The context menu is not showing on the long press

Comment: @Amith `R.id.booksLV` is that a listview id?

Comment: can you post your xml code for `list item` ?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972945/custom-listview-and-context-menu-how-to-get-it

Comment: @ Tamilan @ Abhishek V i have updated the question plz have alook

Comment: @Amith Are you using `custom adapter` or `ArrayAdapter`. If you are using the custom adapter post the xml code for individual list items.

Comment: @AbhishekV am using custom adapter I Have updated the question plz have a look

Comment: Please post the onCreate() method for the Activity.

Comment: Does "ENTERED IN THE CONTEXT MENU BLOCK" get printed?

Comment: @ mike No it does n't

Comment: I would guess that you're having resource id conflicts, given the different layouts you're using. Try removing all but one layout xml, comment out the ifs, and use the one setContentView. You should clean and rebuild the project after you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code for context menu on Listview..

**First Register your content menu on listview..**

```
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
registerForContextMenu(mListView);
```

**Add menu on content menu...**

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                    View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Add");
        menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Rename");
        menu.add(0, 3, 2, "Delete");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        if(item.getTitle().equals("Add")) {
            //Add code
        } else if(item.getTitle().equals("Rename")) {
            //Rename code
        } else if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
            //Delete code
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: am using custom adapter

Comment: custom adapter for what ? ContextMenu or ListView??

Answer (score 0):

You must add a longclicklistener to your view in your onCreate method

```
this.objListView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Here open the context menu
        openContextMenu(this.objListView);
    }
});
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Is your onCreateContextMenu() method called?

if yes, have you tried calling the super after adding the items:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    System.out.println("ENTERED IN THE CONTEXT MENU BLOCK");
    if (v.getId() == R.id.booksLV) 
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        String objBook = userVector.get(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(objBook);
        String[] menuItems = {"Edit","Delete" };
        for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }

    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```