# Contextual action bar not working for ListActivity and BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, listactivity

I've a class that extends ListActivity and another one that extends BaseAdapter. When i start the class ListActivity, i fill a List of objects and pass it to Adapter.

I'm trying to show a context actoin bar when the user select one or more itens from list but i'm stuck. I've tried to many ways and the only that i found to do something close is to put a listener on method getView() from Adapter - but when i do it, i can not perform multiple selections and the context action bar still not working.

What is missing to display a context menu and to select the itens from ListView?

```
public class ChatActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode arg0, int arg1, long arg2,
                    boolean arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}


public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.chat_row, parent, false);

        /*convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ColorDrawable drawable = ((ColorDrawable)v.getBackground());
                if(drawable == null || drawable.getColor() == Color.GRAY){
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                //etc
            }
        });*/
        return convertView;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

register contextMenu after setAdapter on listview list this way..

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

or if above method not work than you can create contextmenuListner for your view of custom layout.. like this way

```
v.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
```

more description in other SO answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4001019/942224

**OR**

you can use [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) . here you can display your custom view as a popup with respect to position of your view.. so it will work same as your context menu.

[demo](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285)

Comment: I've tried that...not working. I mean it works but the menu appear like a popup..i want to do a context action bar.

Comment: a lot of code for a look around. android has a native solution for action bar and i'm looking for what im doing wrong not a work around.